# Doing Recurrent event Survival analysis (Counting Process) in Python

Tags: python, survival-analysis, recurrent

I want to find a way to do Survival Models for Recurrent Events in Python, also using the Counting process approach with CoxPH. In Counting Process Approach, it is expecting start-time and stop-time. But the fit method of CoxPHFitter in lifeline is expecting only a single duration column for time. I can't find any alternative method in Python for handling the same.

Would you please provide any advice for recurrent events in survival analysis with Python.

I've also been trying other libraries like Sksurv which seem to be less capable than Lifelines, so I'm sticking to that.

Highly appreciate your answers.